# How to specify a lambda function as comparator to a class std::map member variable

Tags: c++

How to use a custom comparator for a class `std::map` variable using lambda function. I'm getting error as `error: 'comp' is not a type, std::map<std::pair<std::string, int>, int, decltype(comp)> mapp(comp);`. This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

auto comp = [] (const std::pair<std::string, int>& p1, const std::pair<std::string, int>& p2) {
    if (p1.second > p2.second)
        return true;
    else if (p1.second == p2.second)
        return p1.first < p2.first;

    return false;
};

class A {
    // below also doesn't work
    /*static constexpr auto comp = [] (const std::pair<std::string, int>& p1, const std::pair<std::string, int>& p2) {
        if (p1.second > p2.second)
            return true;
        else if (p1.second == p2.second)
            return p1.first < p2.first;

        return false;
    };*/
    std::map<std::pair<std::string, int>, int, decltype(comp)> mapp(comp);

public:
    A() {

    }

    void add(const std::string& name, int score) {
        
    }

    std::string get() {
        return "";
    }
};

int main() {
}
```

Comment: In your map, key is a pair and value is an int. Your comparator should also have a pair of pair and int, right?

Comment: "*How to use a custom comparator for a class std::map variable using lambda function.*" Can you not just use a named struct?

Comment: @kiner_shah the lambda function takes two pairs of type `std::pair<std::string, int>` as parameters

Comment: @NicolBolas that works, but why not with lambda function?

Comment: Try initializing `mapp` in the constructor `A() : mapp(comp) {}`

Comment: It should (or could) be `mapp{comp}`.

Comment: @kiner_shah can you post that as an answer with some explanation, so that I can close this post.

Comment: @Evg, is `()` not preferred for some reason? It should work right?

Comment: @Harry, I will post an answer.

Comment: @kiner_shah It shouldn't. Please see linked dupes for an explanation.